# simulate a click in StageWebView

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I'm working on a flex mobile project now.

I've created a StageWebView and call function loadString()

```
var str:String='<a href="#.E9.81.8B.E7.87.9F.E7.8B.80.E6.B3.81">bookmark</a>'
                  +'<span id=".E9.81.8B.E7.87.9F.E7.8B.80.E6.B3.81">bookmark</span>';
webview.loadString(str);
```

It's a simple sample that if you click on the bookmark and you can get access to it.

But I want to put the content in the tag  into a spark list. And get the same result when I click the list which needs some kind of simulation of a click in a webView.

Is there any possibilities of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

using StageWebViewBridge you can send events to your swf. i dont know the details how to work with it, but it should be straight forward. :)

simply register the click on the html tag using javascript and bridge it over to actionscript.

http://code.google.com/p/stagewebviewbridge/